# How to get the name of checked checkboxes and store them in a database with using php

Tags: php, checkbox, mysqli

I have 4 checkboxes in html, and at the same time, only 2 can be selected from them. I would like to store the selected ones in a database, but I'm not sure how to put that into code. So if you could help me guide a way to storing the checked in checkboxes in a database, that would be really appreciated!

```html
            <div id="chooseTeacher" style="margin-bottom:24px;">
                <label id="selectTeacher" class="form-control">Select your teacher(s)</label>
                <table style="width:auto;text-align:left;margin-bottom:1px;margin-top:13px" >
                    <tr>       
                        <th style="font:inherit;display:flex;">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="archer" name="archer" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
                            <label for="archer" style="margin-right:68px;"><span></span>Miss Archer</label>
                  
                            <input type="checkbox" id="craig" name="craig" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
                            <label for="craig"><span></span>Miss Craig</label>
                        </th>
                        <th style="font:inherit;padding-right:110px;display: flex;"> 
                            <input type="checkbox" id="devine" name="devine" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
                            <label for="devine" style="margin-right:65px;"><span></span>Miss Devine</label> 
                                                               
                            <input type="checkbox" id="dorrity" name="dorrity" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
                            <label for="dorrity"><span></span>Miss Dorrity</label>  
                        </th>                   
                    </tr> 
                </table>
            </div>
```

(IN THE SNIPPET THE CHECKBOXES CAN'T BE SEEN BECAUSE I USED ANIMATIONS WITHIN CSS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML change to:

```
       <div id="chooseTeacher" style="margin-bottom:24px;">
            <label id="selectTeacher" class="form-control">Select your teacher(s)</label>
            <table style="width:auto;text-align:left;margin-bottom:1px;margin-top:13px" >
                <tr>                            
                    <th style="font:inherit;display:flex;">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="archer" name="teachers[]" value="archer" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
                        <label for="archer" style="margin-right:68px;"><span></span>Miss Archer</label>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="craig" name="teachers[]" value="craig" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
                        <label for="craig"><span></span>Miss Craig</label>
                    </th>
                    <th style="font:inherit;padding-right:110px;display: flex;"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" id="devine" name="teachers[]" value="devine" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
                        <label for="devine" style="margin-right:65px;"><span></span>Miss Devine</label> 

                        <input type="checkbox" id="dorrity" name="teachers[]" value="dorrity" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:9999px;" onclick="countCheckedBoxes(this)">
                        <label for="dorrity"><span></span>Miss Dorrity</label>  
                    </th>                   
                </tr>   
            </table>
        </div>
```

In PHP (I think that your form has been send by POST method):

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
    $teachers = (isset($_POST['teachers']) && is_array($_POST['teachers'])) ? $_POST['teachers'] : []; // Here will be array with values (value="") of selected checkboxes.
    $c = count($teachers);

    if($c == 0)
        // not selected
    else if($c > 2)
        // selected more than 2
    else
    {
        // additional check
        $permitted = ['archer', 'craig', 'devine', 'dorrity'];

        $continue = false;
        foreach($teachers as $t)
        {
            if(!in_array($t, $permitted))
                $continue = false;
            else
                $continue = true;
        }

        if($continue === true)
        {
            // you can save to database
            $teacher1 = $teachers[0];
            $teacher2 = $teachers[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you! I wasn't sure about how to get the different names of teachers to be saved in the database but you wrote it clearly, so thanks again for doing that !

Comment: No problem! I'm so happy that I could help!

Comment: What exactly would you put in the array? Or would you just leave it as it is?

Comment: Oh i've sorted it, don't worry about it !

Comment: My code check that key teachers is available in $_POST array. If yes check that the $_POST['teachers'] is array. If again yes then save to $teachers. If no $teachers is equal empty array. What could be in the array is here: $permitted = ['archer', 'craig', 'devine', 'dorrity'];

Answer (score 0):

The value that will be posted when using a checkbox is contained inside it's **"value"** tag.

So maybe you should change your code to something like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="archer" name="selectedTeacher" value="archer" />Archer
 <input type="checkbox" id="archer" name="selectedTeacher" value="craig" />Craig
 <input type="checkbox" id="archer" name="selectedTeacher" value="devine" />Devine
 <input type="checkbox" id="archer" name="selectedTeacher" value="dorrity" />Dorrity
```

if you are looking for saving more than one checked option, this would be the recommended approach:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="archer" name="selectedTeacher[]" value="archer" />Archer
 <input type="checkbox" id="archer" name="selectedTeacher[]" value="craig" />Craig
 <input type="checkbox" id="archer" name="selectedTeacher[]" value="devine" />Devine
 <input type="checkbox" id="archer" name="selectedTeacher[]" value="dorrity" />Dorrity
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense now ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving different names to checkbox give a common name to all of them and assign them value as per your need. For e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="names[]" value="archer" />Miss Archer<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="names[]" value="craig" />Miss Craig<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="names[]" value="devine" />Miss Devine<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="names[]" value="dorrity" />Miss Dorrity<br />
```

Then you can simply retrieve selected values like:

```
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    { 
       if(!empty($_POST['names']))
        {
           foreach($_POST['names'] as $selected)
           {
             echo $selected."</br>";
           }
       }

     }
```

Comment: This really helped, thanks for the short explanation as well !